# When trying to create a new com. aspose. pdf. Document(contentFilePath), the stamped pdf crashes with Exception

Tags: java, pdf, itext, aspose

There is in PDF version 1.2, the stamp is put ONLY if you
create PdfStamper in a new version (New PdfStamper (reader, FOS '\0', true) - the last parameter is responsible for the new version),
but when you try to create a new com.aspose.PDF.Document (contentFilePath) in stamped PDF format crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.l1if.l1v.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.l6if.lf.lf(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.l0h.l0p.lj(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.PageCollection.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.l1h(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.lI(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.Document.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

in the debug I see the suppressedException error UnmodifiableRandomAccesslist in the collection of pages

Unfortunately I can't attach the pdf file due to confidential data in it.
Aspose 20.10, Itext 5.0.5.

```
PdfStamper stamper = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
PdfReader reader = null;
String contentFilePathOut = "C:\\DISTR\\out.pdf";
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\DISTR\\source.pdf");
    reader = new PdfReader(fis);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(contentFilePathOut, true);
    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fos, '\0', true);
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Hello people!"), 250, 750, 0);
} finally {
    try {
        if (stamper != null) {
            stamper.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }

    try {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) {

    }
    try {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
}
try {
    com.aspose.pdf.Document pdf = new com.aspose.pdf.Document(contentFilePathOut);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ServiceException(e);
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.l1if.l1v.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.l6if.lf.lf(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.l0h.l0p.lj(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.PageCollection.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.l1h(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.lI(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.Document.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Have you checked whether your iText code before your Aspose use does create a proper file? You after all explicitly ignore all exceptions which that code may throw during closing...

Comment: @mkl I added creating an error exception instead of ignoring it - there are no errors

Comment: New pdf file is created, opened by Acrobat, and stamped

Comment: I fixed your stack trace to match that in your comment. Without the file itself to test, though, I have no idea how to analyze this.

Comment: @papaJones, it looks like you're able to resolve your issue. However, please note that Aspose related issues are advised to be reported in the official Aspose Support Forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where they can be addressed and their resolution progress can be tracked appropriately. On the other hand, we also honor the privacy of our customers, and your files are also kept confidential there. This is Asad Ali and I work as a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.